# Install not adding all Content files

Tags: visual-studio, installation, clickonce

I have some xml files I want to distribute with the project. The Build Action is set to Content and the Copy to Output Directory is set to Copy always. When I publish, I see all the xml files in my content folder; however, when I install using ClickOnce, these files are missing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the project settings->Publish->Application Files... the xml files under Publish Status must be changed from Data File(Auto) to Include.

Comment: Hi Travis Yeik, so glad to hear that your issue is solved and you can mark this useful workaround as answer when you have free time, it will help other community members to search this. It just a reminder :)